# How to get Html.RenderAction to use my parameters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this in my RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Promo",
    url: "Promo/{slug}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Promo", action = "Index", slug = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

In PromoController.cs:

```
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult Index( string slug = "" )
{
    // code that uses slug
}
```

Then in a cshtml page I'm trying to do:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Promo", "drink");}
```

But the "drink" parameter is not getting passed to my controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Promo", new { slug = "drink"});}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can I eliminate "Index" somehow? It's kind of redundant.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify that `"drink"` should be passed to the `slug` parameter:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Promo", new { slug = "drink" });}
```

You can leave out `"Promo"` as long as you are staying within the same controller, but the action name is always required.